# Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(\ln n)^3}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

I was trying to find if the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(\ln n)^3}{n^2}$ converges or diverges. But I couldn't solve the question and I looked at the solution in [here](http://www.fen.bilkent.edu.tr/~otekman/math102/s10/fq2.html). In that page, Limit Comparison Test is used with $\frac{(\ln n)^3}{n^2}$ and $\frac1{n^\frac32}$ and the limit found is 0. And it is conclued that the series converges. In my textbook, it says that this limit should be a finite number bigger than 0 in order to use Limit Comparison Test. So how does this work in this question, am I missing something?

Comment: It is enough to use $\ln n \le n^{1/6}$ starting from some point $N_0$, (i.e. $n\ge N_0$) to have an upper bound for the series.

Comment: Link points to surface area calculation?

Comment: oh sorry, one minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are positve sequences such that $a_n/b_n\to 0$ and
$$
\sum b_n<\infty
$$
(i.e. converges  to a finite value), then $\sum a_n<\infty$. To see this note that
$$
a_n<b_n
$$
for sufficiently large $n$ (say $n\geq l$ since $a_n/b_n\to 0$) whence
$$
\sum_{n=l}^\infty a_n\leq \sum_{n=l}^\infty b_n<\infty 
$$

Comment: It makes sense that it should converge this way. So if the limit is 0 we can only talk about convergence of the series, but we cannot talk about divergence of them, right?

Comment: In the above formulation, if $\sum b_n$ diverges, then we cannot conclude that $\sum a_n$ diverges. However if $\sum a_n$ diverges, then $\sum b_n$ diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{(\ln n)^3}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}}=0,$$you have that $\frac{(\ln n)^3}{n^2}\leqslant\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ if $n$ is large enough. So, since the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^{3/2}}$ converges, so does your series, by the direct comparison test.

Comment: So, do we use Direct Comparison Test rather than the Limit Comparison Test?

Comment: Yes. I will add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you state the limit comparison test.

Setup: Let $a_n,b_n>0$ and consider two series $\sum a_n,\sum b_n$.

One version: If $\lim a_n/b_n=c\in[0,\infty)$, then $\sum b_n$ converges implies $\sum a_n$ converges.  Similarly if $\lim a_n/b_n=c\in(0,\infty]$, then $\sum a_n$ diverges implies $\sum b_n$ diverges.

*Proof*: If $\lim a_n/b_n=c<\infty$, then $\sup a_n/b_n=c'<\infty$ (because only finitely many terms are $>c+\varepsilon$), so comparison test yields the conclusion.  The other statement is just the contrapositive form, swapping the roles of $a,b$.

The version in your textbook probably says: If $\lim a_n/b_n=c$ is finite and nonzero, then $\sum a_n,\sum b_n$ either converges together or diverges together.  This is combining the two results above.

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly the case. Now I understand, thanks for explaining.